# Javascript Canvas edge detection

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas

I would like to achieve this kind of image processing effect in Canvas :

[WebGL image processing](http://schibum.blogspot.fr/2013/03/webgl-image-processing.html)

What i need is an edge detection algorithm or explanation to draw only black pixels or border element ( such as a face for example ) of the image that an user can submit.

cheers

Comment: Are you wanting something like this (see the edge detection part of the link):  http://www.i-programmer.info/news/105-artificial-intelligence/5127-jsfeat-javascript-image-processing-library.html

Comment: Thanks I didn't see this library and the Canny edge effect could be something good to play with. I'm gonna try with this one thanks very much !

Comment: @arlg did you ended up using Canny edge effect? What it a good solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used JsFeat as suggested by markE, cheers !

http://inspirit.github.io/jsfeat/

Answer (score 10):

Following your idea, the first step is the Edge detection. The example below shows hot to detect edges using [MarvinJ](http://www.marvinj.org). Having the edges, you might get the object contour.

**Input Image**:

[image]

**Edge Detection:**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

image = new MarvinImage();
image.load("https://i.imgur.com/ZHgkM9w.jpg", imageLoaded);

function imageLoaded(){
  var imageOut = new MarvinImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
  
  // Edge Detection (Prewitt approach)
  Marvin.prewitt(image, imageOut);
  // Invert color
  Marvin.invertColors(imageOut, imageOut);
  // Threshold
  Marvin.thresholding(imageOut, imageOut, 220);
  imageOut.draw(canvas); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.marvinj.org/releases/marvinj-0.7.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="344"></canvas>
```